# I think there is a problem with my url encoding

Tags: google

I took someone's advice and started encoding my image sources, but Google doesn't seem to be able to decode them.

I probably did something wrong, because basically Google is taking the full path as the image's name.

See [this page](http://easydiablo3.com/post/2012/06/14/The-Horadric-Hamburger.aspx) as an example. If you go on the top most thumbnail and do "Save as", you will see the path is not being decoded.

Should I stop decoding or am I doing it wrong? Should I encode only the image name itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone is looking for the answer, you only need to encode the actual image name. What was going wrong is that I was encoding the `/` thus removing its intended meaning.

Remember to only encode parts that can be invalid, such as image names, query string, etc.

Cheers!